# variable before array java book line

Tags: java

Good evening,

I am reading the java book and have encountered the following code where i seem not to grasp the need of a variable A before the array's i'nt variable in this particular line  `str += A[i];`

Maybe somebody would be able to help me get the idea?
For additional clarification i am including the full code from the book
Thank you for your help beforehand!

```
concat = (A,n) -> { // parentheses around (A,n) are required!
    String str;
    str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        str += A[i];
    System.out.println(str);
};  // The semicolon marks the end of the assignment statement;
    //      it is not part of the lambda expression.
String[] nums;
nums = new String[4];
nums[0] = "One";
nums[1] = "Two";
nums[2] = "Three";
nums[3] = "Four";
for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
   concat.process( nums, i );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the type of concat so just for the example I've created a Functional Interface "Concatenator"

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Concatenator{
    public void process(String[] parameterA, int parameterN);
}
```

So...

```
concat = (A,n) -> { // parentheses around (A,n) are required!
    String str;
    str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        str += A[i];
    System.out.println(str);
};
```

is a **Lambda function** which takes two Parameters A and n, if you translate the Lambda function into an anonymous class you would get

```
Concatenator concat = new Concatenator() {
    @Override
    public void process(String[] A, int n) {
        String str;
        str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            str += A[i];
        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }
};
```

Which would do exactly the same.

So just think of A and n as parameter names.

Comment: yep! thanks , but i dont know what exactly does this A do on the line str += A[i]; ,

Comment: A is of type String[] so basically, you add the element at index "i"  of the array "A" to the string "str". (+= means "append" for Strings)